# link_to helper not showing "target" attribute in _blob.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I want to put target="_blank" attribute in a link into an Active Storage Blobs partial view (app/views/active_storage/blobs/_blob.html.erb), but attribute is not shown in final html.

#app/views/active_storage/blobs/_blob.html.erb

```
<%= link_to blob.filename, rails_blob_path(blob), target: "_blank" %>
```

In final HTML target="_blank" is not shown:

```
<a href="/rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBDZz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--48145f82f0b597246f7579fe56b06f563320fe15/file.pdf">file.pdf</a>
```

In fact, for testing, I put <a> HTML tag instead of link_to helper and doesn't work either.  However, in another view it works.

I tested with ID attribute and doesn't work either.

**Ruby version:**  ruby 3.2.2 (2023-03-30 revision e51014f9c0) [x64-mingw-ucrt]

**Rails version:** Rails 7.0.6.

**OS:** Windows 11.

For your help thank you, very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're rendering [Action Text](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_text_overview.html), then the HTML will be sanitized.  The [`render_action_text_content`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7-0-stable/actiontext/app/helpers/action_text/content_helper.rb#L12) helper method uses the `Rails::Html::Sanitizer.safe_list_sanitizer` and will strip out the `target` attribute by default.

One way to test what is happening is to go into the Rails console and do this:

```rb
content = ActionText::Content.new('<a target="_blank" href="my_url">my text</a>')
helper.render_action_text_content(content)
 => "<a href=\"my_url\">my text</a>"
```

To allow the `target` attribute, you could add this to an initializer and then restart your app:

```rb
ActionText::ContentHelper.allowed_attributes << 'target'
```

This will allow the `target` to get through:

```rb
content = ActionText::Content.new('<a target="_blank" href="my_url">my text</a>')
helper.render_action_text_content(content)
 => "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"my_url\">my text</a>"
```

Note that the reason that the `target` attribute is stripped out by default is to prevent against tabnabbing.  See [this post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/187865/is-noreferrer-enough-to-secure-links) for more info on the related attacks and how you can use `noreferrer` in the `rel` attribute to prevent security issues if you do decide to allow the `target` attribute.